# Error List Freaking Out in VS 2008 while in large Aspx Files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I've been having this irritating issue lately. The site I'm currently working on has large aspx pages with tons of client side js code. While I'm typing the Error List window will keep opening and closing at the bottom of VS (where I have the window docked). I mean constantly. This is beyond aggravating as you can imagine. It's happening to a coworker as well. Does anybody else have this issue? Any solutions? (other than smaller pages)

We've got 2008 Pro SP1. I've turned off every JS feature I can find since with pages this large it slows the VS to a crawl while it tries to parse it. I've tried closing the Error list completely but it just re-opens itself.

Thanks in advance,
Geoff

Comment: Perhaps you need to rethink the title!

Answer (score 1):

1. Try deleting the .user file in the project directory
2. Use Add/Remove programs to do a repair on VS2008
3. If neither of those work, copy the markup to a new project and attempt to reproduce.  If you can reproduce this issue then update this question with details.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the options that were causing the issue.
1. Options->Text Editor-> Miscellaneous, 
    un-check "Formal HTML on paste
2. Options->Text Editor->JScript->Formatting
    un-check The boxes under "Automatic Formatting"